# ThreeJS - THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere() Gives Error: NaN Position Values

Tags: three.js

I am creating a simple THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry using Threejs.  The surface is a geologic surface in the earth.

This surface has local gaps or 'holes' in it represented by NaN's.  I have read another similar, but older, post where the suggestion was to fill the position Z component with 'undefined' rather than NaN.  I tried that but get this error:

THREE.BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere(): Computed radius is NaN. The "position" attribute is likely to have NaN values.
PlaneBufferGeometry {uuid: "8D8EFFBF-7F10-4ED5-956D-5AE1EAD4DD41", name: "", type: "PlaneBufferGeometry", index: Uint16BufferAttribute, attributes: Object, …}

Here is the TypeScript function that builds the surface:

```js
AddSurfaces(result) {
    let surfaces: Surface[] = result;

    if (this.surfaceGroup == null) {
      this.surfaceGroup = new THREE.Group();
      this.globalGroup.add(this.surfaceGroup);
    }
   

    surfaces.forEach(surface => {
      var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 'blue', side: THREE.DoubleSide });
      let mesh: Mesh2D = surface.arealMesh;
      let values: number[][] = surface.values;

      let geometry: PlaneBufferGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(mesh.width, mesh.height, mesh.nx - 1, mesh.ny - 1);
      var positions = geometry.getAttribute('position');


      let node: number = 0;

      // Surfaces in Three JS are ordered from top left corner x going fastest left to right
      // and then Y ('j') going from top to bottom.  This is backwards in Y from how we do the 
      // modelling in the backend.
      for (let j = mesh.ny - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        for (let i = 0; i < mesh.nx; i++) {
          let value: number =  values[i][j];

          if(!isNaN(values[i][j])) {
            positions.setZ(node, -values[i][j]);
          }
          else {
            positions.setZ(node, undefined);   /// This does not work?  Any ideas?
          }
          node++;
        }
      }
      geometry.computeVertexNormals();

      var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
      plane.receiveShadow = true;
      plane.castShadow = true;


      let xOrigin: number = mesh.xOrigin;
      let yOrigin: number = mesh.yOrigin;

      let cx: number = xOrigin + (mesh.width / 2.0);
      let cy: number = yOrigin + (mesh.height / 2.0);

      // translate point to origin
      let tempX: number = xOrigin - cx;
      let tempY: number = yOrigin - cy;

      let azi: number = mesh.azimuth;
      let aziRad = azi * Math.PI / 180.0;

      // now apply rotation
      let rotatedX: number = tempX * Math.cos(aziRad) - tempY * Math.sin(aziRad);
      let rotatedY: number = tempX * Math.sin(aziRad) + tempY * Math.cos(aziRad);

      cx += (tempX - rotatedX);
      cy += (tempY - rotatedY);


      plane.position.set(cx, cy, 0.0);
      plane.rotateZ(aziRad);
      this.surfaceGroup.add(plane);
    });
    this.UpdateCamera();
    this.animate();
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have read another similar, but older, post where the suggestion was to fill the position Z component with 'undefined' rather than NaN.

Using `undefined` will fail in the same way like using `NaN`. `BufferGeometry.computeBoundingSphere()` computes the radius based on `Vector3.distanceToSquared()`. If you call this method with a vector that contains no valid numerical data, `NaN` will be returned.

Hence, you can't represent the gaps in a geometry with `NaN` or `undefined` position data. The better way is to generate a geometry which actually represents the geometry of your geologic surface. Using `ShapeBufferGeometry` might be a better candidate since shapes do support the concept of holes.

`three.js r117`

Comment: Could this problem in computing the bounding sphere happen if some of the geometry has repeated values? I have very large BufferGeometries (uint8array position attributes) being generated and they're causing this problem but none of the values are NaN (indeed an unsigned type cannot hold a NaN value)

Answer (score 1):

```
THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry:: parameters: {
        width: number;
        height: number;
        widthSegments: number;
        heightSegments: number;
    };
```

widthSegments or heightSegments should be greater 1 ,if widthSegments  < 1 ,widthSegments may be equal 0 or nan.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the [help]. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was happening when I tried to create a beveled shape based on a single vector or a bunch of identical vectors - so there was only a single point. Filtering out such shapes solved the issue.