# react-three - 3D model displays a blank white square on Android phone devices

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I am developing a portfolio application using Nextjs and 3D libraries such as Three and React-Three.

I use Vercel to deploy the app.

I am experiencing a problem where the 3D model in the deployed app is displaying as a blank white square on Android phones:

- Xiaomi red mi note 7 / MI browser
- Samsung s10 / chrome browser.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Deployed Site: https://portfolio2-nu-ruddy.vercel.app/

Git Repo: https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio

**3D model component:**

```
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader";
import { useLoader, Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Suspense, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { OrbitControls, Preload } from "@react-three/drei";
import Loader from "./Loader";

const Computers = ({ isMobile = false }) => {
  const gltf = useLoader(GLTFLoader, "/desktop_pc/scene.gltf");
  return (
    <mesh>
      <hemisphereLight intensity={0.15} groundColor="black" />
      <pointLight intensity={1} />
      <spotLight
        position={[-20, 50, 10]}
        angle={0.12}
        penumbra={1}
        intensity={1}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize={1024}
      />
      <primitive
        scale={isMobile ? 0.7 : 0.75}
        position={isMobile ? [0, -3, -2.2] : [0, -3.25, -1.5]}
        rotation={[-0.01, -0.2, -0.1]}
        object={gltf.scene}
      />
    </mesh>
  );
};

const ComputersCanvas = () => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

    setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);

    const onMediaQueryChange = (event: MediaQueryListEvent) => {
      setIsMobile(event.matches);
    };

    mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", onMediaQueryChange);

    return () => {
      mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", onMediaQueryChange);
    };
  }, []);
  return (
    <Canvas
      frameloop="demand"
      shadows
      camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
      gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true }}
    >
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <OrbitControls
          enableZoom={false}
          maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
          minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
        />
        <Computers isMobile={isMobile} />
      </Suspense>
      <Preload all />
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default ComputersCanvas;
```

Comment: Did you try remote debugging? [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)

Comment: The bug is not reproducible on my iPhone 13. It has to be clear on which device and browser it is happening.

Comment: @sungryeol it happens on Android phones: Samsung s10 for example.

Comment: @harshShah I didn't try remote debugging yet.

Comment: @sungryeol the browsers it happens on are: chrome and Mi

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been reproduced on my Samsung Galaxy A32.

## Solution

The problem lies in `Hero.tsx`; add `alpha: true` to the webGL configuration.

```
// Hero.tsx
<Canvas
  frameloop="demand"
  shadows
  camera={{ position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25 }}
  // add alpha: true here.
  gl={{ preserveDrawingBuffer: true, alpha: true }}
>
{/* ... */}
</Canvas>
```

## Explanation

The reason isn't very clear at current moment. I can only guess, since the console message shows that the r3f instances are not properly destroyed. The message was fetched from `chrome://inspect`.

[image]

`WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost., THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.`

These messages mean that every time a 3d canvas gets mounted, there's another unnecessary webGL instance is created. Proper implementation of multiple canvas should hold only one webGL instance and share it among canvases [manually](https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-multiple-canvases-vxphz) or by using [portal](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/tutorials/v8-migration-guide#createportal-creates-a-state-enclave).

I assumed that webGL buffer is somehow got corrupted, so forced the background to be transparent by changing the configuration.

The error is not reproducible in desktop browser; this may need another deep investigation.

Comment: I deployed the update, but unfortunately, the white issue still persists. Despite no warning signs, a white square still appears in place of the 3D model. Additionally, the app sometimes crashes altogether.

Comment: @ItayTur are you sure you only applied above solution? it should have nothing to do with the app crash. and try run without mobile-desktop code altogether. it's the only possible reason that may cause the problem.

Comment: I tried commenting out the mobile desktop code, but the problem remains.
You can view the change here: https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/commit/f73aa0014d42bd03229bac5582f1aca406ca90da.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to debug your code. Something is preventing rendering of your Canvas component in android's chrome browser.
I have tried to resolve it and it seems to be working.
Could you try updating Computers.txs file with the following code.?
The remaining code should be same.

```
const ComputersCanvas = () => {
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)");

        setIsMobile(mediaQuery.matches);

        const onMediaQueryChange = (event: MediaQueryListEvent) => {
            setIsMobile(event.matches);
        };

        mediaQuery.addEventListener("change", onMediaQueryChange);

        return () => {
            mediaQuery.removeEventListener("change", onMediaQueryChange);
        };
    }, []);

    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!initialized) {
            setInitialized(true);
        }
    }, [initialized]);

    if (!initialized) {
        return <div></div>
    }

    return (
        <Canvas
            frameloop="demand"
            shadows
            camera={{position: [20, 3, 5], fov: 25}}
            gl={{preserveDrawingBuffer: true, alpha: true}}
        >
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
                <OrbitControls
                    enableZoom={false}
                    maxPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
                    minPolarAngle={Math.PI / 2}
                />
                <Computers isMobile={isMobile}/>
            </Suspense>
            <Preload all/>
        </Canvas>
    );
};
```

This works because initially we are rendering div element.
After the first render we are forcing to it to re-render with Canvas element.
Hope this resolves your issue.
Thanks :)

**Update:**
I am sorry I am unable to resolve your issue because it needs experimenting with different approaches. However I can give some suggestions and ideas that may ease your process.
The main issues lies with canvas behavior on android/mobile browser.
Browser limits the number of canvas context. I have seen it to be eight in general, but they can be any number.
You may have noticed the console message `THREE.WebGLRenderer: Context Lost.`

- You can either use one canvas context and reusing the same.This could be cumbersome, especially with your app.
- You can try a workaround in your app in a way that your app listens to scroll and create canvas only for the view that is active/visible. In the current state, your app is creating canvas for all the views/components on the page.
- You can of course try googling and searching, how others overcame similar situation.
- You can increase the bounty on this question to attract attention and wait for the good solution.
- etc.

Comment: The recent update has made some improvements. However, I still face issues where the white square reappears or the app crashes upon refreshing the page, accompanied by the error message: 
`Application error: a client-side exception has occurred`.

Comment: Could you try in incognito mode? because I am unable to reproduce the issue again after the update. May be, it could be happening because of cache?
If this doesn't solves, can you provide any specific instructions/steps to reproduce it?

Comment: I am not so deep in this area, but does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62183371/threejs-three-buffergeometry-computeboundingsphere-gives-error-nan-position) provides any insights or helps?
Because the console is showing the same error multiple times in android chrome browser.

Comment: I noticed the error, but I don't think it's the root cause. The error appears on the desktop as well, but the app functions properly.

I have attempted to resolve the issue by using incognito mode, in the Chrome browser, and my Samsung S10 phone, but unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: Just for debugging purpose, could you try commenting out <OrbitControls> inside every canvas and test it's impact on mobile?. Just to see if it crashes.

Comment: I have commented out the <OrbitControls/>, and you can now review the modifications made in this link: https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/commit/fac4ce411d2b46870d66a7f6dafb1edede6044a8
The app doesn't crash anymore, but the white square issue still persists

Comment: Does it work fine, without any crash on android browser?

Comment: The app doesn't crash anymore, but the white square issue still persists

Comment: Ok thanks, I will debug it and will be back with a solution most probably. Also whenever you test it, test it in incognito (for this android issue).

Comment: Forgot to mention, during testing please keep reactStrictMode:false in next.config.js.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61523632/why-when-i-put-my-component-into-react-strictmode-its-constructor-called-twice

Comment: I set `reactStrictMode: false`, you can view it in this commit: https://github.com/ItayTur/Portfolio/commit/f9e87831300d6c0efbed7c640f1f046d3e207795
It seems that the app crashes frequently and when it does work, the white square appears. I tested in incognito, chrome, Samsung s10.

Comment: Hi @ItayTur, I have replied in my answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: I appreciate all the help you provided. Thank you so much.